# Target domain events not firing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, chrome-devtools-protocol

Why do the Target domain events not fire? There is not supposed to be a Target.enable method but for some reason it still does not work. The `Target.createTarget` method does work though.

```
const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");

async function example() {
  let client = await CDP();

  const { Network, Page, Browser, Input, Target, DOM, Runtime } = client;
  await Page.enable();

  Target.targetInfoChanged((param) => {
    console.log("targetInfoChanged", param);
  });

  Target.receivedMessageFromTarget((param) => {
    console.log("receivedMessageFromTarget", param);
  });

  Target.targetCreated((param) => {
    console.log("targetCreated", param);
  });

  Target.targetDestroyed((param) => {
    console.log("targetDestroyed", param);
  });

  Page.loadEventFired((param) => {
    console.log("load", param);
  }); 
  
  await Target.createTarget({ url: "https://www.google.com/" });

  await new Promise(() => {});
  return
}

example();
```

Answer (score 4):

A fun thing about the **Target Domain** is that it does not have an `enable` method. However, it does have [setDiscoverTargets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-setDiscoverTargets) method, that is used to enable some of the events (as documented). Call it with `discover` set to `true` and it should work for you :)